# Git operations that requires authentication are not working

Tags: git, macos

I'm using a Mac, and typing git pull nothing happens. The terminal is blocked and no error appears, nothing happens. It should ask me for my credentials but no popup or text appears. Same problem if I try to use git push. Git commit works instead.

I tried uninstalling and installing git but it didn't work

Running `GIT_TRACE=1 git pull` I got

```bash
10:45:57.431007 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git pull
10:45:57.435625 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok
10:45:57.442808 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok
10:45:57.448499 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https origin repositoryName
10:45:57.454243 git.c:750               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin repositoryName
10:45:57.454664 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin repositoryName
10:45:57.675229 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: '/usr/local/share/gcm-core/git-credential-manager-core get'
```

Comment: can you try running `GIT_TRACE=1 git blahblah` and tell us what it shows? (edit the question for that). _and_ welcome to SO!

Comment: do you run the command in the local git repository?

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A I cloned the repository and I run the command in the terminal

Comment: you should `cd <repo-name>` after cloning and then run `git pull`

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A it's what I did

Comment: try `git status` and add it to question to help finding the issue

Comment: It appears that you've installed (and configured Git to use) `git-credential-manager-core`, but that it's not working correctly. I have no idea why that would be the case, but you might consider trying one of the other macOS credential managers to see if they work better for you.